# Result always FALSE

Tags: android, multithreading, exception

I am new to programming. I don't understand what's wrong. This code always returns FALSE, but the letter is sent. Pay attention to the "result" variable. May be I not properly described it. Thanks in advance!

```
public class Send extends javax.mail.Authenticator 
{   
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
    private String user;   
    private String password;   
    private Session session;
    protected boolean result;
    public String sss = "";
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "LOG";

    public Send(String user, String password) 
    {   
        this.user = user;   
        this.password = password;   
        Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false"); 
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
    {   
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }   

    public boolean sendMail    (final String subject, 
                                final String body, 
                                final String sender, 
                                final String recipients,
                                final String FileName) 
    {
        Thread SendThread = new Thread() 
        { 
            public void run() 
            {                   
                try
                {
                    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
                    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   

                    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
                    message.setSubject(subject);          
                    message.setDataHandler(handler);
                    MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();       

                    FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource(FileName) 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public String getContentType() 
                        {
                            return "application/octet-stream";
                        }
                    };
                    attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDataSource));

                    String Fname = new File (FileName).getName();

                    attachmentPart.setFileName(Fname);   

                    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                    multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);            
                    message.setContent(multipart);           
                    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0) 
                        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
                    else  
                        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
                    Transport.send(message);
                    result = true;
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SENDED");
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    result = false;
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FAILED");
                }
            }
        };
        SendThread.start();         
        return result;
    }   
    ......
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    SendThread.start();         
    return result;
```

You're (potentially) returning the value of `result` before the thread finishes. If you need the send to be asynchronous, you can't return its result immediately - it's not available yet. If you need to notify someone/something when the send is done, you'll need to code for that in the thread.